# Checked Toggle between TMenuItems in group

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have three menu items I would like to toggle between one another with a check.

The first one is default checked = true and the other two are false

I would like to have the check mark show next to the one clicked

I tried setting the group index of the three different from the rest of all the other menu items, but that didn't seem to work. All three menu items have autocheck = true

do I have to manually handle all this by code?

thanx

Comment: You also have to set the menuitems `RadioItem` to `True` (in addition to setting the group index, for all three of them).

Comment: Can you post some code or set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Supplement: This is a `delphi` code question. What does it have to do with jsfiddle? There's no `js` involved. You might want to look at the tags before commenting on or trying to answer a question. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following for each of the three menu items:

1. Set `AutoCheck` to `True`.
2. Set `RadioItem` to `True`.
3. Set the `GroupIndex` for all three items to the same value.

This will result in a bullet rather than a tick being placed next to your menu item. That's by design. These menu items operate like radio buttons (hence the bullet) rather than check boxes (which would have ticks).

Comment: +1. I'd add "and greater than 0" to item 3 for clarity; assigning them all to the same `GroupIndex := 0` will not work, but that's not clear from the docs.

Comment: Hmmm... Must have changed (or I originally had something screwed up when I "learned" this; I've always used > 0 since). It's probably the second - a quick test shows you're correct at least in D2007. :-) Thanks.